# Adding handlers to Dynamically Created Context Menu

Tags: vb.net, events, contextmenu

I need to populate a context menu from a database at run time.  I do not know the number of items that will be in the list, so I would like to handle the click event in a single place.  How do I declare the handler so I can tell which menu item actually triggered the click.

```
Public Function GetBookmarkContextMenu(ByVal aBookmark As Bookmark) As System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu

    Dim myContextMenu As New Controls.ContextMenu
    myContextMenu.Name = "BookmarkMenu" 

             For Each aMailingList As MasterService.FalconBookmarkMailingListType In GlobalUserSettings.MailingLists

                Dim mySubMenuItem As New Controls.MenuItem
                mySubMenuItem.Name = "MailingListName" & aMailingList.ID.ToString
                mySubMenuItem.Header = aMailingList.Title
                AddHandler (myMenuItem.Click), AddressOf ForwardToList_Click
                mySubMenuItem.IsEnabled = True
                myMenuItem.Items.Add(mySubMenuItem)
            Next
            myContextMenu.Items.Add(myMenuItem)

            return myContextMenu
End Function

Public Sub ForwardToList_Click()
    'How do I know which of the dynamically created items was clicked?
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ForwardToList_Click() should include parameters for the sender and event args:

```
Public Sub ForwardToList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
'...
End Sub
```

"sender" is the control that caused the event, which is what I believe you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Can't add a comment so I'll put it here. Excellent reply from AundyKarthick easily set out 
my result was this:

First create a contextmenustrip on the form in this case ContextMenuStrip1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  NamesTableAdapter.Fill(DataSet.Names)
  For Each element In DataSet.Names
     Dim mnuitem As New ToolStripMenuItem
     mnuitem.Name = element.Item(1)
     mnuitem.Text = element.Item(1)
     AddHandler (mnuitem.Click), AddressOf ToolMenuItem_Click
     ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(mnuitem)
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub ToolMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
    textbox1.Text = sender.name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim mnuitm As New ToolStripMenuItem
mnuitm.Name = name_cbk.Items(i)
mnuitm.Text = name_cbk.Items(i)
AddHandler (mnuitm.Click), AddressOf item_Click
menulist.Items.Add(mnuitm)
```